Call Recording on a Headset on Android
We have a phone recording app that uses accessibility service: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/PhoneCallRecorder
Testing on Android 12 on a Pixel 6, call recording works well with 'RECORDING SOURCE: VOICE_RECOGNITION' after turning on 'OPEN ACCESSIBILITY SETTINGS' in the app. However, when testing with a headset with the same settings, the phone call receiver's voice is absent from the recording.
How to fix this issue?

Just so you know-  the Play Store will not accept this app using accessibility in this way.  If this is a personal app you're ok, but if you want to upload it to the app store it is against Google's terms of service

Thanks Gabe, I am not planning to upload this to the app store.
